# Mutants and Masterminds, Affects other beneficial effects and power levels

Tags: optimization, mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Hi so I've been told I should split up my earlier question to allow for more focused answers.

I feel this is prevented by Power Levels as it acts directly rather than through circumstantial modifiers however I want to know how it resolves,

- Punch-Dude is built to his Power Level in his defenses. Shield
  Lass comes along and applies an area selective Impervious Protection
  effect.

My prediction is that only the impervious part of the power resolves. However I could also belive that it could reduce Parry and Dodge by an amount equal to the protection to keep it all under PL. Or the Power just failing to apply altogether.

- Punch-Dude is built to just below his Power Level in his defenses.
  Shield Lad comes along and applies an area selective Impervious
  Protection effect.

Here I assume that the Protection applies until up to PL, and then acts as the above case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that, by the book, Shield Lass will only apply the Impervious part of her Protection, and Shield Lad would only boost Punch-Dude to his Power Level. Some GMs might allow the power to "fill in" for missing defenses, such as if you are Vulnerable, Weakened, Afflicted, etc, but by the book, you can't boost someone past PL outside of circumstance bonuses (and most GMs look askance on attempts to do that consistently rather than actually circumstantially).

The one exception that I've seen most GMs apply is boosting people below your PL (such as bystanders) up to your PL, or the "campaign PL". Again, I don't think it's technically correct by the book, but I think it's a reasonable way to rule things.